# Junit4 unit tests running inside eclipse, using java.util.logging - cannot see log output

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3, junit4, java.util.logging

Using Maven build system under eclipse.

I have just switched by project from using Apache Commons Logging to Java Utils Logging, as it has to live in an environment where Java Utils Logging is the main logger (Google App Engine), and other libraries that I use already use it (Restlet). One of the features I like in eclipse is to be able right click on a function thats marked with @test and select "Run as Junit Test". When I do this now, I see no logging output. I have created a file

src/test/java/resources/logging.properties

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level=INFO
my.great.package.level=FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
```

But still I see nothing when running test inside Eclipse. Before it used to all work beautifully with commons logging and log4j. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if Java Logging can auto-detect configuration files in the same way that `log4j` can.

Have you tried specifying where the configuration file is for the test runner, e.g.:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=path/to/logging.properties
```

You can add this to the system properties via the VM Arguments text box in the Eclipse Run Configurations dialog.

You can also configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` with the same system property so you get logging during your build - if desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion - I have just tried adding this to the "Run Configuration" for the Junit method in the "program arguments" and the "vm arguments" as -Djava.util.logging.config.file=src/test/java/resources/logging.properties and the "environment" section filling in the dialog box, and I still get no logging

Comment: @user859955 Ok. I assume that the properties file you're using when running on `GAE` is producing logging you desire? If it is, try referencing that from your test runner and see what happens.

Comment: @user859955 Also, I think you should only add system properties to `VM Arguments` text box in the Eclipse `Run Configurations` dialog.

Comment: thanks a lot - I have it working now - once I specified the path correctly as a fully qualified path.

Comment: Another way to do this is to set the mentioned property programatically on the jUnit Test `Runner` via `System.setProperty()`

Comment: The full path must be put under `VM Arguments`.